# Non-static method isGooglePlayServicesAvailable and getErrorDialog cannot be referenced from a static context

Tags: java, android, android-studio, google-cloud-messaging, google-play-services

I am writing this code and it shows the error non-static method GoogleApiAvailability.isGooglePlayServicesAvailable(Context context) and GoogleApiAvailability.getErrorDialog (Activity activity, int errorCode, int requestCode) cannot be referenced from a static context.

```
package com.xamarin.gcmexample;
import android.app.Dialog;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import com.google.android.gms.common.ConnectionResult;
import com.google.android.gms.common.api.GoogleApiClient;
import com.google.android.gms.common.GoogleApiAvailability;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class Main extends AppCompatActivity {
    TextView msgText;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        msgText = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.msgText);

    }
    protected void IsPlayServicesAvailable ()
    {
        int resultCode = GoogleApiAvailability.isGooglePlayServicesAvailable(this);
        if (resultCode == ConnectionResult.SUCCESS){
            msgText.setText("isGooglePlayServicesAvailable SUCCESS");

        }else{
            GoogleApiAvailability.getErrorDialog(this, resultCode, 1).show();
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Nurlan has already pointed the right answer.

Replace your method

```
protected void IsPlayServicesAvailable() {
    int resultCode = GoogleApiAvailability.isGooglePlayServicesAvailable(this);

    if (resultCode == ConnectionResult.SUCCESS){
        msgText.setText("isGooglePlayServicesAvailable SUCCESS");
    } else {
        GoogleApiAvailability.getErrorDialog(this, resultCode, 1).show();
    }
}
```

by

```
protected void IsPlayServicesAvailable() {
    int resultCode = GoogleApiAvailability.getInstance().isGooglePlayServicesAvailable(this);

    if (resultCode == ConnectionResult.SUCCESS){
        msgText.setText("isGooglePlayServicesAvailable SUCCESS");
    } else {
        GoogleApiAvailability.getInstance().getErrorDialog(this, resultCode, 1).show();
    }
}
```

Comment: Probably it works, but not on API 19 emulator with 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:17.0.0'.

Comment: @CoolMind Why not? I'm no expert in Android, but the mentioned methods still appear in the API: https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/common/GoogleApiAvailability

Comment: Sorry, I meant that this method returned SUCCESS.

Answer (score 1):

by googling, this [link](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/common/GooglePlayServicesUtil#public-method-summary) says: **static** `isGooglePlayServicesAvailable(Context ctx)` is deprecated, use **non- static** `isGooglePlayServicesAvailable(Contex ctx)`. (And there is `public static GoogleApiAvailability getInstance ()` for you ;) )

Comment: How could I use  "public static GoogleApiAvailability getInstance ()" in the above code ? Could you Explain, please .

Comment: @ManasMaity, get instance of _GoogleApiAvailability_ and from instance use **non- static isGooglePlayServicesAvailable(Contex ctx)**
`GoogleApiAvailability instance = GoogleApiAvailability.getInstance();
int res = instance.isGooglePlayServicesAvailable(Contex ctx);`